# multiple UIView animations 3rd unintentionally cancels first

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am having trouble with some code. 
I am calling 3 UIView Animations. If I run just two, Ring and another everything works ok. If I run all three the first "Ring" animation will reset to its original location in the storyboard as if the animation gets canceled or reset.

```
-(IBAction)home2{
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    CGRect frame = ring.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 461;
    frame.origin.y   = 57;
    [ring setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
{
    UIImage *secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BigNames1.png"];
    [UIView transitionWithView:words duration:0.0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    words.image = secondImage;[[words superview] bringSubviewToFront:words];
    }completion:nil];
}
{   UIImage *secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RealPhoto1.png"];
    [UIView transitionWithView:imagesilhouette duration:1.0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    imagesilhouette.image = secondImage;[[imagesilhouette superview] bringSubviewToFront:imagesilhouette];
    }completion:nil];

}

}
```

I've tried breaking each out into subroutines to troubleshoot. Again, if I run 3, the first will reset once the 3rd starts. I hope the answer is simple. I'm new at coding so I bet its a easier error on my part.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` in the `options` of the animations.